# After deleting /home url from Wordpress general settings I cannot display site's urls

Tags: home-url

I delete the /home url from setting and I cannot access admin page any more. I change wp-config.php file this

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.domainname.com/home');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.domainname.com/home');
```

so after that I can access the admin page but only landing page is displaying on web other urls display ERORR 404
Then I change the wp-config.php file back to normal and change the setting from phpMyadmin but the result is same.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your hosting place, use phpMyAdmin to edit the wp-config table in the WP database. Look for two entries to enter your full site URL.

Those entries must be there in order to access your site admin.

Comment: thank you i figure out the problem. Update all the pages and done.